# problems with Timer on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm having a problem with my timer on swift. When I press the play button once it works fine and adds one second every second but when I play it twice it adds 2 seconds every one second and so on. This is my code.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var time = 0
var minute = 0

@IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!

func increasedTimer()
{
    time++
    timerLabel.text = "\(minute)" + "m  " + "\(time)" + "s"

    if time == 59
    {
        minute++
        time = -1
    }
}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject)
{
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("increasedTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject)
{
    timer.invalidate()
    time = 0
    minute = 0
    timerLabel.text = "0m  0s"
}

@IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject)
{
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: As suggested by Maddy you should toggle the play button, easiest option can setting the flag or enable/disable based on the current state

Answer (score 1):

Every time you tap `play` you create and start an additional timer.

You have a few options to fix this.

From a user experience point of view, you need to enable/disable your three buttons (Play, Pause, Stop) appropriately. It makes no sense that the user can tap Play a 2nd time while the timer is going. And of course the Pause and Stop buttons shouldn't be enabled until Play has been tapped.

So start by fixing the user interface so the buttons make sense. Once that is done, you won't have the problem in your current code since the user won't be able to tap Play twice without first pausing or stopping.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Start by doing some basic research about enabling and disabling buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In the short term, every time you play put another `timer.invalidate()` before starting a new timer.  Definitely better to disable the play button.

```
button.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage1, forState: .Normal)
button.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage2, forState: .Highlighted)
button.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage2, forState: .Disabled)
```

Examples of things you can do.  You can supply different images for a greyed out play button, a selectable play button.  Etc.  Then change the forState.  More options available then shown.

Or you can just change the text shading in the button with:

```
button.enabled = true
button.enabled = false
```